# PHP - Repeated operations get slower and slower

Tags: php

I have a PHP script which creates a tree with all possible moves for a game up to 15 steps ahead.

The script that creates the moves looks something like this:

```
function createPossibleMoves($heroId, Hero $Hero, Move $LastPossibleMove = null) {    
 $moves = array();
 foreach ($Hero->Attacks as $attackid => $attack) {
        if ($attack['uses'] < 1) continue;
        $usesLeft = $attack['uses'];

        $LastPerformedMoveIterator = $LastPerformedMove;
        while (is_a($LastPerformedMoveIterator, "Move")) {
            if ($LastPerformedMoveIterator->heroId == $heroid && $LastPerformedMoveIterator->attackId == $attackid) $usesLeft--;
            $LastPerformedMoveIterator = $LastPerformedMoveIterator->PreviousMove;  
        }

        if ($usesLeft < 1) continue;

        if ($attack['targets'] === 1) {
            foreach ($this->Monsters as $monsterid=>$Monster) {
                $Move = new Move($heroid, $attackid, $this, array($monsterid));
                $Move->setPreviousMove($LastPerformedMove);
                $moves[$Move->getMoveHash()] = $Move;
            }
        } else {
            $maxTargets = $attack['targets'];
            if ($maxTargets > count($this->Monsters)) $maxTargets = count($this->Monsters);
            $combinations = new Combinations($this->getMonsterIds(), $maxTargets);
            foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
                $Move = new Move($heroid, $attackid, $this, $combination);
                $Move->setPreviousMove($LastPerformedMove);
                $moves[$Move->getMoveHash()] = $Move;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the constructor for the Move class looks like this:

```
public function __construct($heroId, $attackId, Battlefield $Battlefield, $targets) {
    $this->Battlefield = clone $Battlefield;
    $this->PreviousBattlefield = $Battlefield;

    $this->Hero = $this->Battlefield->getHero($heroId);
    $this->heroId = $heroId;

    $this->attackId = $attackId;
    $this->Attack = $this->Hero->getAttack($attackId);


    foreach ($targets as $monsterId) {
        $this->Targets[] = $this->Battlefield->getMonster($monsterId);
    }
    $this->targetList = $targets;
}
```

The `Battlefield` class holds a single state of the Battlefield where the actions are performed, with all the `Monster` instances, and all the `Hero` instances. When a `Battlefield` is cloned, each of it's `Monster` instances and `Hero` instances are also cloned.

I've noticed that when I try to create around ~6000-7000 `Move` instances with the `createPossibleMoves` function, at the beginning, a `Move` instance is created in around 0.0005 seconds, but towards the end, this amount jumps up to a whopping 0.1 second / `Move` instance.

What could be the reason of this sudden time jump? I tried allowing more memory for this PHP script, but it doesn't help this situation.

Comment: Is your question really why 6000-7000 in-memory objects makes PHP slow? Or is there a specific question about refactoring here?

Comment: Can you paste whole code ? and php version ?

Comment: @WillardSolutions my question is indeed why 6000-7000 in-memory objects makes PHP slow. My question is, that does this small amount of in-memory objects make PHP this slow? If yes, what would help? Would working with simple arrays instead of objects speed things up?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure but 6.000 or 7.000 objects in memory doesn't make PHP slower, but a for loop of 6.000 - 7.000 items does.

Comment: @Osakr you are saying that the problem is that the for loop is too big for PHP? and if I don't totally refactor the code, there is no way of making this faster in PHP?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I don't even know if you loop all the objects. But I see a for loop inside the constructor, that makes 7.000 for loops which could slow down the  script. Anyways, for sure there are people that would tell you better since I am not an expert

Comment: @Osakr yes, but the problem is that not the whole function is slower for this amount of loop, a single iteration of the loop is getting slower and slower over the time.

Comment: use an IDE that analyses memory stack traces when you run the script -- such as PhpStorm.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Try commenting out the `foreach` in the `Move` class or if that's not possible only process the first child and see if that gives better performance. Usually the culprit in these situations is nested foreach loops. Also, it is very possible that the problem is in `getHero()`, `getAttack()`, `getMonster()' and not the `Move` constructor itself.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Also, if it is related to looping through objects switching to arrays will help with performance, but if you need/want the features of an object then `ArrayObject` is a fair compromise in performance. If I remember correctly, arrays are about 3x faster than objects, but only about 1.5x-2x faster than `ArrayObject`.

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail what the `while` loop does?

Comment: Can you identify exactly what section of code gets slower in later iterations, and how the speed reduces - does it get progressivly slower, or jump at a certain point? I suspect the issue is either memory allocation (garbage collector), or something similar, for example exhausting disk write cache

Comment: For example, i see you have cyclic references between `Battlefield` and `Move`

Comment: @Steve I am benchmarking the `createPossibleMoves` function, which over the passing of time, should get faster instead of slower (because there are less targets to choose from, meaning less operations, but instead of getting faster, it is progressively getting slower. Starting from an execution time of `~0.0005s`, towards the later part of the script, I am getting execution times of `~0.16s` consistently. I was also benchmarking the creation of a `Move` class, and getting simmilar results there also, seen in my original question.

Comment: I also tried manually unsetting things that I don't need, because I was thinking about garbage collector issues also, but that didn't help neither. I am yet to check, on what percentage my disk writes operate while running the script, but a naive question here: if I am using memory to store things, why is the disk ussage affecting things? I am not writing to databases, not reading/writing to files, only echoing ocassionaly to the command line.

Comment: @SvenHakvoort the while loop iterates over all the previous moves, in a list like manner, to find out the actual amount of uses left for a specific move. The program works in the following way: iterate ahead for a depth of x, trying out all possibilities, find the best possibility based on a heuristic function, then perform the first move of that possibility. Next turn, do this again for the second hero. Because I didn't want to clone the Hero objects, I've decided to simulate the moves, when looking forward, and thus needed this option to see if a move was already used in the iteration or no.

Comment: Yeah its not disck write cache then, that was just an example (i dont know what your code does beyond whats included in the question - for example cloning a battlefield might write to disk..).

Comment: For clarity, it is this particular loop that slows down per iteration?: `foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
                $Move = new Move($heroid, $attackid, $this, $combination);....}`

Comment: @Steve I could provide an extended review of the code, the only problem is, that I already rewrote part of it (based on other suggestions) which helped to decrease the total time of the script, yet didn't resolve the problem I am encountering. Dunno if stackoverflow will be happy, if I change the above code in it's entirety.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186534/discussion-between-adam-baranyai-and-steve).

Comment: What is the content of Move class?

Comment: What is the content of `Move` class? I can see when you instantiate your class you are also injecting current class, in effect you are creating an array of connected tree of objects `Move` instead you must be making a array of objects. You should analyze how these two classes are joined.

Comment: Shouldn't `$LastPerformedMove` be `$LastPossibleMove` as defined in the function parameters or is that variable in the global scope?

Answer (score 7):

Below solution is trying unset variable and invoke garbage collection explicitly every 1000 move calculation.

This can slow your queries below 5000 but it should enhance above 5000, although because you didn't provide full parent class and Hero and Move Class , I can't test this solution.

PS: For the love of god please comment your code so any observer can quickly understand you intentions of the logic.

```php
function createPossibleMoves($heroId, Hero $Hero, Move $LastPossibleMove = null) {    
 $moves = array();
 foreach ($Hero->Attacks as $attackid => $attack) {
        if ($attack['uses'] < 1) continue;
        $usesLeft = $attack['uses'];

        $LastPerformedMoveIterator = $LastPerformedMove;
        while (is_a($LastPerformedMoveIterator, "Move")) {
            if ($LastPerformedMoveIterator->heroId == $heroid && $LastPerformedMoveIterator->attackId == $attackid) $usesLeft--;
            $LastPerformedMoveIterator = $LastPerformedMoveIterator->PreviousMove;  
        }

        if ($usesLeft < 1) continue;

        if ($attack['targets'] === 1) {
            foreach ($this->Monsters as $monsterid=>$Monster) {
                $Move = new Move($heroid, $attackid, $this, array($monsterid));
                $Move->setPreviousMove($LastPerformedMove);
                $moves[$Move->getMoveHash()] = $Move;

            }
        } else {
            $maxTargets = $attack['targets'];
            if ($maxTargets > count($this->Monsters)) $maxTargets = count($this->Monsters);
            $combinations = new Combinations($this->getMonsterIds(), $maxTargets);
            foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
                $Move = new Move($heroid, $attackid, $this, $combination);
                $Move->setPreviousMove($LastPerformedMove);
                $moves[$Move->getMoveHash()] = $Move;
            }
        }
        // unset $Move
        unset($Move)

        // Invoke garbage collection explicitly every 1000 move
        if (count($moves) % 1000 == 0) gc_collect_cycles();
    }
}
```